# Railsでhas_many throughのモデルの条件で検索するには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

以下のような関係にあるモデルがあります。

`Group -< GroupUser >- User`

`Group` に `User` が所属できます。

「`ユーザーA`と`ユーザーB`と`ユーザーC` "のみ" が所属している`Group`を検索するにはどのように書くべきでしょうか？

今は`Group`を1つ1つ確認している状態で非常に効率が悪いです。

よろしくお願いします。

- Rails 5.1.3
- ActiveRecord 5.1.3

Comment: GroupUser は ActiveModel でしょうか?それとも HABTM?
いづれにせよ Group を数えるのではなく、 GroupUser を数えるのが良いかと思います。Group から見たら GroupUser の件数は必ず3件になるのですよね?

Answer (score 1):

@naopontan さんもおっしゃっていますが、  `group_users` テーブルに対して検索を行う方が早いと思います。

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord # GroupUser が rails に取られてたので、これで代用
  self.table_name = 'group_users'
end

UserGroup
  .select(:group_id)
  .where(user: [user_a, user_b, user_c])
  .group(:group_id)
  .having('count(user_id) = 3')
```